# Show Select dropdown in the Category Blog menu

Tags: menu-item, menu-parameters

Is there any default options or modules in Joomla 3 that allow display the select dropdown in the Category Blog page so that I can choose how many articles per page to show?

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't. The amount of articles is defined by multiple params. See ContentModelCategory line 189:

```
$limit = $params->get('num_leading_articles') + $params->get('num_intro_articles') + $params->get('num_links');
```

Comment: So could you advice what I can do with it? Cannot decide, it should be a component or a plugin which will wrap the blog view with the form and change those params when I change the dropdown item.

Comment: I understand that I shouldn't edit core files. But how can I add functionality to it with overrides? Guess it could be managed through a custom template, but I want to set this dropdown for every template.

Comment: Nope. Not possible.

Comment: Well .. you could write a new (frontend) component which displays articles.

Answer (score 0):

What about just highlighting the steps?

1. List categories then
2. Select then
3. either the options listed on the Select options

Comment: Answers are for providing resolving information, not for flaming about the content quality in this community.  I'm going to edit away the inflammatory parts of this answer (because they will not be tolerated), but I'll give you an opportunity to re-[edit] this answer if you want to contribute to better content here.  If you leave your answer as-is, it may be downvoted as unhelpful.  If you edit the answer to re-apply unhelpful/negative/inflammatory text, then this will indicate what kind of user you intend to be and appropriate actions will be taken by the moderation team.

Comment: If you intend to continue contributing here, and I hope that you will, please take the [tour] and read [answer].